# How to programmatically set the default color of all objects to gray using Autodesk Platform Services v7 viewer APIs for progress tracking purposes?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm working with Autodesk Platform Services v7, and I'm trying to find a way to programmatically set the default color of all objects to either no color or gray. This is for progress tracking in building construction, where users need to manually color objects that have completed construction.

### The issue

I've searched through the official documentation, and while I did come across a method that allows me to change the color of selected objects, this doesn't match my needs as I want to change the color of all objects at once.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setselectioncolor-color-selectiontype

### Expected behavior

I'm looking for a code snippet that can automatically set the default color of all objects to either no color or gray.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

### Code

```js
import * as THREE from "three";

function MyCustomExtension(viewer, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
}

MyCustomExtension.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);
MyCustomExtension.prototype.constructor = MyCustomExtension;

MyCustomExtension.prototype.onToolbarCreated = function (toolbar) {
  const viewer = this.viewer;
  const button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button("show-env-bg-button");

  button.onClick = function (e) {
    const instanceTree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
    const rootId = instanceTree.getRootId(); // it was 1
    const color = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    viewer.setThemingColor(rootId, color, viewer.model, true);
  };
}

MyCustomExtension.prototype.load = function () {
    const viewer = this.viewer;
}

MyCustomExtension.prototype.unload = function () {
    return true;
};

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
    "MyCustomExtension",
    MyCustomExtension
);
```

-------------------Mar 14, Added-----------------------

I will explain further with screenshots.
First, I want to change the color of all objects in this picture to gray. For example, there is a big yellow box in front of me, and I want to change it to gray. There is also a blue fence, which I want to change to gray. There is also some yellow piping, which I would like to change to gray. After we change everything to gray, we would like to paint them another color as a construction progress control.

[image]

If I just click on this yellow box to select it, it turns light blue. Next, when I run the code you taught me and then click on it, it becomes transparent.

[image]
[image]

So, I have not been able to achieve what I wanted to achieve... What I wanted to achieve is to make all objects that are painted in various colors gray once and for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do this, is to use `setThemingColor()`.

You can set this function on the root **dbid** (in most case it's the **dbid** 1, to be confirmed with **instance tree** or **derivative tree**) and apply this color to all objects thanks to the **recursive** option.

```
NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor(1, new THREE.Vector4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1), NOP_VIEWER.model, true)
```

However, it does NOT replace the object color. So if you reduce the alpha channel of your color, the original object color and the theming color will be blended.

What do you mean by 'no-color' ? If you want transparent objects (maybe with only the outline), you can hide theses objects and let **Ghost hidden objects** option do the job ?

Comment: Let me try that ASAP!

Comment: What is NOP_VIEWER?

Comment: `NOP_VIEWER` is a variable that store the viewer reference. You can easily try functions on the Viewer in the browser console. But in your code you can replace it with your `viewer` reference. The `Vector4()` is used to defined the color in RGBA (from 0 to 1). The values provided give an opaque light gray. [setThemingColor](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive)

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I added the code, could you take a look at it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work' ? You set 0.5 opacity with a very light color, so you probably don't see the difference. Can you try with a red opaque color like`Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1)` ?

Comment: Added description. I also changed the color code as you said, but it continues to be transparent. And I have to click on the object to change the color.

Comment: I know your answer is right because this codepen works well but I still need your help... as I wrote above, it does not color. https://codepen.io/autodesk-platform-services/pen/bGxMyVe?editors=0010

Comment: You forgot to `return true` in extension load. I tried your code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexpiro/pen/NWLzMpV?editors=0010) and it's working.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I processed and pasted it a bit. The `return true` is already there. I think the cause is that the version of THREE.js is 150, but what do you think, it has to be the same 71 as Autodesk Platform Services or it won't work.

Comment: You don't need to import `THREE`. It's already used by the APS (Forge) Viewer.

Comment: Yes! I finally made it! Alex! You're the best and I want to like you 10 times!